# How to solve blender's additive parenting?

Tags: bones, constraints, parent

If I parent a bone(A) to a master bone and give it a 'child of' constraint to get influenced by a certain bone(B), Moving the master bone will exaggerate the movement of bone(A) as if it's going **additive**. This is because it's parented to bone(B) which is already a child of the master bone. But this kind of situation is necessary where you want multiple bones in a hierarchy and one master bone to move all of it without the grandchild bone going additive. Is there a specific way to do this or Blender simply doesn't allow it?

Comment: please tell when this situation is necessary, show some drawings and what your armature is supposed to do, I'm sure there are some workarounds

Comment: @moonboots Well, here's a test bend file that i recreated just as an example since I can't share the main project.


https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b1oLp6zS88K8Lby-KquZPXXm__Ta2RgB/view?usp=sharing

If i move the master bone, it goes additive. And I need the constraint for the 'grandson' bone so I can key the influence as and when required.

Comment: You need it to be sometimes child of master, sometimes child of son? Could you give a precise situation where you would need this kind of bone?

Comment: Not sometimes. But I want the son and grandson bones to coordinate with each other through constraints, so I can manipulate the influences. But both of them have to be governed by a master bone. So if I wanted to move the character elsewhere, I just have to move the master bone.

Comment: maybe show a practical case to make it more understandable